# Счётесли для нескольких столбцов

Tags: excel

Друзья, всем доброго времени суток.

Буду рад если поможете решить вопрос с программированием в Excel.
Имеется таблица, содержащая данные по некоторым фирмам. [image: Фирмы]

Требуется посчитать количество работников для каждой организации, имеющий статус "да".
Для этого я составил такую формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2="да"; СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:A33;A2))
```

Насколько я понял, она далека от действительности. Я бы с радостью написал функцию на том же Питоне, но нельзя.

Кто-нибудь знает как написать формулу корректно? Дополнительные столбцы делать тоже нельзя.
Сам Excel-файл можно скачать в Гугл-Диске
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1siCm7Jz8I2FTSFxnyr7sDbXXtqtuR0IY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104703556348297089571&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Откуда там 12 для А? Их же только 9... Я это узнал прямо в Гугл-таблице с помощью `=sumproduct(A:A=A2;B:B="Да")`

Comment: Да, их 9. Формула некорректная, считает неправильно. Её нужно модифицировать, чтобы считала правильно

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Ну, значит `СУММПРОИЗВ()` подойдет. Чтобы не засорять таблицу этими "девятками", а потом "тройками" для АА, можно использовать `ЕСЛИ()` - тогда количество будет только в первой строке каждой организации: `=ЕСЛИ((A2<>A1; СУММПРОИЗВ(A:A=A2;B:B="Да");"")` и растянуть вниз до конца таблицы. Но обычно такие задачи решают с помощью Сводной таблицы,  результат получается компактнее

Comment: Голосую за сводную таблицу. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN0sR.png

Comment: *=СЧЕТЕСЛИМН(A:A;A2;B:B;"Да")*